# Finding out the intended deserialization type of an Avro byte array before trying to deserialize

Tags: c#, avro

I want to use Avro for network packets in my TCP program.

I would also like to use structs for all my messages, or at least, used pooled objects.

But either approach would need me to know the intended deserialization type before I actually try to deserialize the byte array I'm getting.

I have never used C#'s dynamic before, but this seems like the kind of use-case for it:

```
        var deserialized = AvroConvert.Deserialize<dynamic>(bytes);
        switch (deserialized)
        {
            case AuthenticationRequest auth:
                break;
            case ReconnectionRequest reconnect:
                break;
            default:
                // Unexpected packet?
                break;
        }
```

Which seems fine with the struct approach.

However, there is also the possibility of an unexpected packet type (e.g. a bad actor sending pointless data). At this point in the switch statement, Avro already did the heavy lifting of deserializing this supposed packet.

Is it possible to tell whether an incoming byte array is "worth" trying to deserializing through Avro before actually doing so? Typically (before I found Avro) I would maybe prefix the packet with some bytes to identify the packet type and then calculate if the total size of the array makes sense for that packet. Will I need the same approach or is there a more standard way to control this kind of scenario with Avro?